# LogBack logs to file but fails to log to console (wildfly 10)

Tags: java, spring, wildfly, logback

I am having big trouble trying to get the logging of my application right. I am using wildfly 10.1, spring and logback. My *logback.xml* is located in src/main/resources and looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <Pattern>%d %-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - 
%msg%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="SAVE-TO-FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${jboss.server.log.dir}/amset.log</file>
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </layout>

</appender>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="SAVE-TO-FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>


</configuration>
```

And I have disabled the default wildfly configuration for this project including this *jboss-deployment-structure.xml* file inside my src/main/webapp/META-INF folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
     <exclude-subsystems>
        <subsystem name="logging" />
    </exclude-subsystems>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Both the spring startups logs and my application logs appear in the amset.log file properly, but I don't get anything at the console.

EDIT: what is actually happening is that the STDOUT logs are appearing in the file. And not only mine but all of other applications deployed in the server. The file appender is swallowing all the stdout logging from the server... Don't really know what could be happening.

Any ideas?

Comment: try removing <charset>UTF-8</charset>

Comment: that did not work. Thanks for the try though :)

Comment: check this: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/logback/logback-additivity-example/ and try the additivity flag

Comment: additivity should not be the problem since I am only using the root appender... I just found out that the STDOUT logs are actually appearing in the file, and not only my application's but all of other applications deployed in the server... Its like the file appender is swallowing them all... any ideas?

Comment: Is this an EAR or WAR deployment?

Comment: It is a WAR. I think I am going back to log4j as I don't have more time to work this out... however if anyone knows the answer I am sure someone will appreciate it!